# Acceptance tests for multi-JVM applications

Tags: java, testing, jvm

We're trying to come up with a concept for Acceptance Testing of our JVM product which includes several applications. I'm looking at writing tests  that:

- Will start and stop several JVM applications in individual JVMs, no EE containers involved.
- Will interact with these applications and assert some results (writing to a log file, exit code of the applications ...)

My first trial was a `maven` project with `Junit` that forks the applications with Java's `ProcessBuilder`,like:

```
 new ProcessBuilder("java", app1, vmParameters).start();
 //...
 new ProcessBuilder("java", app2, vmParameters).start();
```

and then workt with the `InputStream` and `OutputStream`, but it feels very cumbersome. The JVMs are started as `surefirebooter***` jars and you can't really see what's going on. 
These tests will eventually run in their own `Docker` container and probably run for days, I was hoping to be able to attach to the container and check what's going on.

Another option would be to start/stop the process directly with scripting, but I'd like to have some integrated reporting capabilities.

Most of the frameworks I've found are thought to be used with EE containers, but I've found nothing for good old `jars` started through a `main` method.

Anyone has a thought how to do this or knows a tool suitable for the job?

Comment: Sounds like a classical CI job. Did you have a look at Jenkins for example.

Comment: @blafasel, of course the maven project  will run in Jenkins, but he needs to know what to run